# what to do on the PR2 robot simulation?

Tags: ros, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I ran the line
roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch

So now I have an empty world and spawned a pr2 robot.
How would I go about making the robot do something? For example waving? Do I just type commands in a new terminal? Very new to ROS :(

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227339/what-to-do-on-the-pr2-robot-simulation?/) by [meep](https://answers.ros.org/users/25977/meep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would start with the [PR2 Simulator Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_simulator/Tutorials) (follow the tutorials link on the [pr2_simulator wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_simulator) ).

The PR2 simulator has been around for a long time, and gazebo has changed a lot since the tutorials were written. If you encounter something which doesn't work the way the tutorials say it should, ask a new question and the community will probably help you figure out how to update the tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1